# How I can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 500 matrices with 3x3 dimensions?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I can apply the Eigensystem command to a single matrix and it worked fine. But it takes me too much time. I want to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of multiple 3x3 matrices at the same time. Please guide me how can I do that.

Comment: Use `Map[]` with `Eigensystem[]` on your list of matrices.

Comment: It's not clear why this should be slow, so please add your code and people can help more.

Answer (score 3):

If your matrices are really only $3\times 3$, then calculating the eigensystem for 500 of them is *very fast*.

Generate some matrices of integers to play with:

```
matrices = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {500, 3, 3}];
```

Calculate their eigenvectors and eigenvalues with arbitrary precision:

```
Eigensystem /@ matrices; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {1.01, Null} *)
```

If your matrices contain machine-precision numbers, or if you can work with machine-precision results, that's even faster:

```
Eigensystem /@ N@matrices; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.00436, Null} *)
```